# How to convert javascritp code used in html forms using return or output in Zapier?

Tags: javascript, html, zapier

I never code in Zapier so I'm little blind here. What is trivial for an experienced coder for me still a challenge. So I need help because I'm a dummy in this kind of knowledge. :-(

I created a trigger in Manychat to trigger a zap and pass to Zapier the height and the weight.

After that, I created an action Run Javascript and to test I pass the values weight = 81 and height= 175

I used a javascript code that I found on the Internet to calc the human BMI, but I still do not understand how to define the function to output the results.

I need to receive the BMI value and the text regarding this result, but I do now know how to write and pass these values using the return ou the output used in Zapier.

```
// Calculate BMI
function getBMImsg(bmi) {
  var bmiTable = [{bmi: 10,   msg: "você deve esta com inanição"}, 
                  {bmi: 15,   msg: "você está muito abaixo do peso"}, 
                  {bmi: 18.5, msg: "você está um pouco abaixo do peso ideal"}, 
                  {bmi: 25,   msg: "você está saudável!"}, 
                  {bmi: 30,   msg: "você está acima do peso ideal"}, 
                  {bmi: 40,   msg: "você está obeso!"}, 
                  {bmi: 50,   msg: "você está com obesidade mórbida!"}];
  var i;
  var text = bmiTable[0].msg;
  for (i = 0; i < bmiTable.length; i++) {
    if (bmi < bmiTable[i].bmi) {
      text = bmiTable[i].msg;
      break;
    }
  }
  return text;
}

function calcBMI(height, weight) {
  var bmi = 0;
  if (height > 0 && weight > 0) {
    bmi = Math.round((weight / Math.pow(height/100, 2)) * 10) / 10;
  }
  return bmi;
}

function bmiFunction() {
  var height = document.getElementById('height');
  var weight = document.getElementById('weight');
  var output = document.getElementById('output');
  var result = document.getElementById('result');
  var bmi = calcBMI(height.value, weight.value);

  if (bmi > 0) {
    output.textContent = bmi.toPrecision(3);
    result.textContent = getBMImsg(bmi)
  }
}
//document.getElementById("bmiform").addEventListener("submit", bmiFunction);
output = {bmiResult: bmiFunction}; //my wrong test to pass values
```

I do not know how to format or pass the result using the return or the output. This is my issue. In this code, the Zapier do not present error but the id shows strange characters instead of the bmi text message that I want to pass to Manychat.

Please teach me how can I do that.

Thanks a lot!

Marco Querini

Answer (score 0):

Like I said before, any code containing `document` **will not** run in Node.js. Even if this code worked in the browser you pulled it from, you'll need to tweak it for a Node environment.

A few quick fixes:

- `var height = document.getElementById('height');` should be `inputData.height` instead (or however you mapped it.
- In `bmiFunction`, you need to store the results on the `output` object:

  ```
  if (bmi > 0) {
    output.bmi = bmi.toPrecision(3);
    output.message = getBMImsg(bmi)
  }
  ```
- For your output, you're returning a function, which isn't what you want. Assuming your other functions are right, the "top level" (outside all functions) should be just: `bmiFunction()`, which will call the above function and set the values in the `output` variable.